# ora-06550 call to a procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

My code is not entering the begin for my procedure call according to the error I am seeing and indicates a possible error with one of the parameters I am passing in:

```
PROCEDURE PRICING_SPLIT
(P_PRICING_PERIOD IN p.pricing_period_code%TYPE,     --say, which is how I’ve tried to correct for this, but no joy.
P_RETURN_CODE OUT VARCHAR2
  ) IS

  BEGIN
```

Instead of:

```
PROCEDURE PRICING_SPLIT
(P_PRICING_CODE IN NUMBER,
  P_RETURN_CODE OUT VARCHAR2
  ) IS

  BEGIN
```

I also have my code in vb.net:

```
    Dim dbConn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dbComm As OleDbCommand

    dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider = MSDAORA;User ID = xxxx;Password = xxxx;Data Source = myDatabase;"
    dbConn.Open()
    dbComm = dbConn.CreateCommand

    dbComm.Parameters.Add("pricing_period", OleDbType.Numeric, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    dbComm.Parameters.Add("return_code", OleDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

    dbComm.CommandText = "enq_pricing.pricing_split"
    dbComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    dbComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbConn.Close()

    MessageBox.Show(dbComm.Parameters("temp").Value)
```

Any suggestions what I might be missing, most gratefully received.

Comment: Try running `SHOW ERROR PROCEDURE TAS_CRIF_SPLIT` in Oracle side, it will tell you the line & source of query error. See [ORA-06550 error](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06550.php) to find out possible cause.

Comment: I was missing a connection string in my code to pass in a variable there

Comment: I ran this and it came back no errors, this is very helpful. Was missing a connection string in my code to pass in a variable. Had it in another part of my code but also needed it here: oParam1.Value = txtPricing_period.Text. Also had a reference assembly to opd.net which was for 11.1. Changed this to 11.2....... If you get a chance can you change TAS_CRIF split to something generic like PROCEDURE PRICING_SPLIT, my bad, Tetsuya Yomamoto